# Java and Excel Spreadsheet connection error

Tags: java, excel

I need my java program to connect to an Excel spreadsheet. 
I have completed the System DSN and have used the code below. However, on run time, an error throws in regards to 'sun.jdbc.obdc.jdbcodbcDriver' on line 4. I have done a lot of research around Stackoverflow and other sites but finding no direct solution.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:[B]Testsheet[/B]");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from [Sheet1$]");

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            while (rs.next()) {

                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                    if (i > 1)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                    String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                    System.out.print(columnValue);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

            st.close();
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.print("Exception: ");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Error: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

Comment: Please post your error message